# Unable to get sliding bottom sheet to not drop below minimum height

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple bottom sheet that I would like to not drop below a certain height (200 pts).

However, whenever my bottom sheet scrolls to the bottom, it drops off the screen and it comes unusable. I would like the animation to be smooth without snap points. My current implementation seems to do everything I want, but I can't seem to get it stop going outsides the bounds at the bottom.

Is there a height adjustment or logical expression I should put in the offset view modifier to get this behavior?

Thank you!

```
public struct FloatingPanel: View {
    // New properties
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 200
    @State var isInitialOffsetSet: Bool = false
    
    public init()
    
    public var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                Color.white
                    .clipShape(CustomCorner(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20))
                
                VStack {
                    Capsule()
                        .fill(Color.gray)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 4)
                        .padding(.top, 5)
                    
                    NavigationView {
                        VStack {
                            Text("this is navigation content")
                        }
                        .background(Color.white)
                    }
                    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .offset(y: offset)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    withAnimation {
                        let startLocation = value.startLocation
                        offset = startLocation.y + value.translation.height
                    }
                }
        )
        .onAppear {
            if !isInitialOffsetSet {
                offset = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 250
                isInitialOffsetSet = true
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
    }
}

struct CustomCorner: Shape {
    var corners: UIRectCorner
    var radius: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min()` to add a lower bounds to the offset. The new offset line would be: `.offset(y: min(UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 200, offset))`

Implementation with `minHeight` variable:

```
public struct FloatingPanel: View {
    // New properties
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 200
    @State var isInitialOffsetSet: Bool = false
    
    let minHeight: CGFloat = 200
    
    public init() {}
    
    public var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                Color.white
                    .clipShape(CustomCorner(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20))
                
                VStack {
                    Capsule()
                        .fill(Color.gray)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 4)
                        .padding(.top, 5)
                    
                    NavigationView {
                        VStack {
                            Text("this is navigation content")
                        }
                        .background(Color.white)
                    }
                    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .offset(y: min(UIScreen.main.bounds.height - minHeight, offset))
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    withAnimation {
                        let startLocation = value.startLocation
                        offset = startLocation.y + value.translation.height
                    }
                }
        )
        .onAppear {
            if !isInitialOffsetSet {
                offset = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 250
                isInitialOffsetSet = true
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
    }
}

struct CustomCorner: Shape {
    var corners: UIRectCorner
    var radius: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}
```

(Also suggest you look into [Presentation Detents](https://www.swiftlyrush.com/using-presentation-detents-in-swiftui/) -- Apple's native solution to this)

Comment: thank you! is there anyway I can stop the height changes from being so jittery/chopping? The animation height changes are very rough. Unfortunately, we're on an ipad and still on io15 to fully use presentationDetents. @ZachtheBoB